# Помогите разобраться в работе слайдера

Tags: javascript

ниже представлена версия кода для работы слайдера на jQuery, к сожалению не могу понять строку

$('#slider img:nth-child('+indexImg+')').fadeIn(500);

а конкретно,синтаксис +indexImg+
P.S. слайдер работает не правильно,переключает первую фотографию с первой(а их 2),помогите понять,в чем ошибка

```
$(function (){
var indexImg =1;
indexMax = $('slider img').length;
function autoCange () { 

        if(indexImg > indexMax) {
            indexImg = 1;
        }           
        $('#slider img').fadeOut(500);
        $('#slider img:nth-child('+indexImg+')').fadeIn(500);
        indexImg++;
    }   
setInterval(autoCange, 4000);       
});
```

Comment: Просто опечатка или недопечатка `$('slider img').length;`

Comment: я не понял Вас,Рустам Гимранов

Comment: Спасибо,Рустам,разобрался